# Fetch API Delete Request Data Returns - null

Tags: javascript, http, fetch-api, http-delete

I'm trying to send a Delete request using Fetch. I get a response status - OK, but data is null. However the request has a body with an object, but I'm unable to see it back in the data received from the request. Here is a sample code.

```
let myObj = {
    test: test1
}

fetch(deleteUrl, {
        method: 'DELETE',
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(myObj)
    }).then(
        response => response.json()
    ).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data) // Here the data is always null, but I want to log the request body(myObj)
    })
```

Comment: "However the request has a body with an object" — Have you confirmed this by checking the Network tab of the developer tools?

Comment: Yes, I did. The status is OK and the request payload shows myObj.

Comment: Unrelated: note that application/json does not have a charset parameter.

Answer (score 0):

From my limited understanding of "fetch", you seem to looking at the *response* data, not the *request* data.